# ToUnixTimeMilliseconds is converting the date to Utc before returning. What if you don't want that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, datetimeoffset

I'm developing a WebAPI. Where I have an Entity called Assignment. Assignment has a property called DateScheduled which is a long, that represents a UnixTimeStamp in milliseconds. Now on creation of an Assignment, I have a method called `BeginningOfDay(long date)` which looks like this

```cs
public static long BeginningOfDay(long date)
{
    DateTimeOffset beg = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(date).Date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return beg.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
}
```

If the user passes in 02-10-2021 21:01:00 the method will give me 02-10-2021 00:00:00.
Now the date that the user passes in is already in Utc. But when calling `beg.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` it's converting it to UTC once again. Which is leading to a lot of problems? I hope you guys understand my issue. When running it locally it's working fine. But on the server, it's messing up because of where it's located at. Given parameter **1633903199** it's returning **1633816800** locally which is correct. But the same parameter on azure is giving **1633824000** which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.Date` use `UtcDateTime` so all your code will be aligned with UTC dates.

The code will be like this:

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(date).UtcDateTime
```

Comment: That's great, but what if I want to remove time from that Date. That was why I used .Date?

Comment: I think you have utc date too